# Converting a roman numeral to integer

Tags: matlab

For a computer science assignment my goal is to convert a character string (the roman numeral) to an integer.  I'm to write a function to do this in Matlab.  My code to do this is shown below.

```
function [x] = roman2decimal(s)
s1 = substr1(s,1);
s2 = substr2(s,2,2);
s = substr2(s, 3, numel(s));
sum = 0;
if (s1~='')
%Case I - if any of these conditions are true
if (s1=='C' && s2=='M')
    sum = sum + 900;
end
if (s1=='C' && s2=='D')
    sum = sum + 400;
end
if (s1=='X' && s2=='C')
    sum = sum + 90;
end
if (s1=='X' && s2=='L')
    sum = sum + 40;
end
if (s1=='I' && s2=='X')
    sum = sum + 9;
end
if (s1=='I' && s2=='V')
    sum = sum + 4;
end
s=s1
s2=substr2(s, 3, numel(s))

end

% case 2 - no case 1 conditions were true
if(s1=='M')
    sum = sum + 1000;
end

if(s1=='D')
    sum = sum + 500;
end

if(s1=='C')
    sum = sum + 100;
end

if(s1=='L')
    sum = sum + 50;
end

if(s1=='X')
    sum = sum + 10;
end

if(s1=='V')
    sum = sum + 5;
end

if(s1=='I')
    sum = sum + 1;
end
s1=s2
s=s2
sum
end


function [c]=substr1(s,pos)
if(pos >= 1 && numel(s) >= pos) c=s(pos);
else c='';
end
end % substr1

function [c]=substr2(s,pos1,pos2)
if(pos1 >=1 && pos2 >= pos1 && pos2 <= numel(s)) c=s(pos1:pos2);
else c='';
end
end % substr2
```

The issue I'm having is that when I call the function for a character string that's more than 2 characters long, s1 always computes to the second character in the string, e.g. for 'CM' s1=M, s2=M.

If I call the substr1 function outside of this function, it works fine (e.g. returns the first character in the string).

I was wondering if there was something wrong with my algorithm/syntax and if you could help?

Much appreciated.

Comment: Just a tip. You might find [`switch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/switch.html) statements helpful. Also, generally [`strcmp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html) should be used to compare strings, not `==`.

Comment: Comparing explicitly scalar characters with `==` seems fine to me...

Comment: @sebastian: Except it can be dangerous (particularly for scalars). `char` is a special data type. `65=='A'` returns true, but `strcmp(65,'A')` does not.

Answer (score 7):

Here is an answer inspired by @Robert, yet quite different:

```
myStr = 'MCMLXXXVIII';

key = 'MDCLXVI';
values = [1000, 500,100,50,10,5,1];

% Calculate the 'weight' of each letter
[~, loc]=ismember(myStr,key)    
relevantValues = values(loc);

% Determine whether we should substract or add
s = [-sign(diff(relevantValues)), 1];
%% To avoid zeros in s    
while ~all(s)
   f = find(s == 0);
   s(f) = s(f+1);
end

s*relevantValues'
```

This vectorized approach minimizes the amount of string operations and avoids `eval` statements.

Comment: +1, I like your approach better than my own =) I'll delete mine (but for the record, it did work for me at least).

Comment: Why  `while`, and not `if`? And why not `s(s==0)=1`?

Comment: @Jonas Though it is rare I have seen numbers like this before: `MIIIM`. I suppose the while is then neccesary to guarantee proper deduction. If the same number is used at most twice sequentially in reduction (as it should be by the book) it could indeed probably be reduced to `s(s==0)=-1`.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is in C and has passed all the 3999 test cases in LeetCode

```
int romanToInt(char* s) {

    int i = 0, value = 0;

    for (int i =0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        switch(s[i]) {
            case 'I':
            if(s[i+1] != '\0' ){
            if(s[i+1] == 'V' ||s[i+1] == 'X' )
            value = value -1;
            else 
            value = value+1;
            }else {
            value = value+1;
            }

            break;

            case 'V':
            value = value + 5;
            break;

            case 'X':
            if(s[i+1] != '\0' ){
            if(s[i+1] == 'L' ||s[i+1] == 'C' )
            value = value -10;
            else 
            value = value+10;
            }else {
            value = value+10;
            }
            break;

            case 'L':
            value = value + 50;
            break;

            case 'C':
            if(s[i+1] != '\0' ){
            if(s[i+1] == 'D' ||s[i+1] == 'M' )
            value = value -100;
            else 
            value = value+100;
            }else {
            value = value+100;
            }
            break;

            case 'D':
            value = value + 500;
            break;

            case 'M':
            value = value + 1000;
            break;



        }


    }
    return value;


}
```